# how to add more than 24 hours in showtimepicker in flutter?

Tags: flutter, timepicker, flutter-datetime-picker, showtimepicker

I have a question about this this timePicker :

this is my code :

```
        final TimeOfDay? picked = await showTimePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
                    return MediaQuery(
                      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
                      child: child ?? Container(),
                    );
                  },
                );
```

that works fine , but i want it to work as some kind of duration for something , so I want it to accept more than 24 hours ( i want user be able to select or add time less than 100 hours )

I tried some other packages but this one looks fine with ui and other stuffs , any hint ? thanks

Comment: you can use textfields.

Comment: Have you tried this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/time_duration_picker)

Comment: it is working fine. for more than 24 hours